# Group rows by a variable in R (knitr::kable)

Tags: r, r-markdown, grouping, kable

I'm trying to group the rows of the `kable` output by the value in the Person column, so the table output is easier to read.

Data for MRE (within an R markdown document, using R Studio 2022.07.1 on Mac OS Ventura 13.2)

```
library ("tidyverse")
library ("knitr")

Person <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
Group <- c("pre", "post", "pre", "post", "pre", "post")
Value <- c("10", "5", "8", "4", "5", "4")

df <- tibble(Login,Group,Value)

knitr::kable(df, format = "pipe")
```

In this output, each row displays its Person value.

I've seen how you can use `pack_rows()` or `group_rows()` to manually define groups, but I would like this to be grouped by Person value, rather than be having to define each Person and their relevant two rows.

The current output looks like this[image]

My desired output looks more like this

[image]

Comment: What does your output would look like? You don't want A to be repeated but keep two rows for each group? Summarise other variables?

Comment: I've updated the body above to show you the current output. And yes, I dont want A B or C to be repeated, but I still want all the Group and Value values to be shown

Comment: There is `kableExtra::collapse_rows` but it seems to be having issues: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/595

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using kableExtra::collapse_rows()...

This approach assumes you are printing to pdf.
There are multiple options within kableExtra to finetune the appearance of the table.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}

library(tibble)
library (kableExtra)

Person <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
Group <- c("pre", "post", "pre", "post", "pre", "post")
Value <- c("10", "5", "8", "4", "5", "4")

df <- tibble(Person, Group, Value)

  kbl(df, booktabs = TRUE) |> 
  collapse_rows(valign = "top",
                latex_hline = "major")

```
````

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could also transform your data to a wider format using `pivot_wider` like this:

```r
Person <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
Group <- c("pre", "post", "pre", "post", "pre", "post")
Value <- c("10", "5", "8", "4", "5", "4")

library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
df <- tibble(Person,Group,Value)
df <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = Group, values_from = Value)
knitr::kable(df, format = "pipe")
```

| Person | pre | post |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 5 |
| B | 8 | 4 |
| C | 5 | 4 |

<sup>Created on 2023-02-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely another good option. I will see if there are any further suggestions relating to my original intention, but if not then this will be my way forward. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use xtabs:

*change "Value" to numeric first

```
df$Value <- as.numeric(df$Value)
xtabs(Value ~ Group + Person)
```

and if you want to present it in all various formats, something along the lines of :

```
Library(gtsummary)
tbl_strata <- df %>%tbl_strata(
strata = Person,
.tbl_fun =
  ~ .x %>%
  tbl_summary(by = Group,
              type = list(Value ~ "continuous"),
              statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{sum}")
)
tbl_strata
```

- note that you have to specify that continuous variables should be presented as such  when using small datasets

is this format maybe a bit closer to what you had in mind?

**edit**:

you can also use a huxtable. They are also nicely compatible with Rmakrdown

okay, have a look at huxtables. they have the added benefit of also beign nicely compatible with Rmarkdown.

```
df <- df %>% hux() %>%
   merge_repeated_rows()%>%
   set_bottom_border(, row = odds, col = everywhere)
df
```

Comment: Thank you for this, that's not quite the desired format. I have updated my original post to give an idea of what I had in mind

Answer (score 1):

I am late on this but I was dealing with a similar issue that I found a solution for. This is for anyone else who might need this as well.

```
library("kableExtra")

Person <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
Group <- c("pre", "post", "pre", "post", "pre", "post")
Value <- c("10", "5", "8", "4", "5", "4")

df <- tibble(Person,Group,Value)

df[,c("Group","Value")] %>% 
  kbl(table.attr = "style='width:25%;'", caption = "Caption",align = "c") %>%  
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", font_size = 12, position = "center") %>% 
  pack_rows(index=rowSums(table(df$Person,df$Group)))
```

[image]